# How can I enable mouse scrolling in tmux without also enabling mouse selection?

Tags: tmux

I currently use `set-window-option -g mouse on`, but this also enables selection inside tmux with my mouse. I'd like to disable this behavior but still keep scrollback working. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can unbind the `MouseDrag1Pane` key in the root table to prevent tmux entering copy mode when you drag, for example:

```
unbind -n MouseDrag1Pane
```